# Copying Specific Rows between CSV Files Python

Tags: python, csv

I have an image folder with images saved with their ids. I would like to search the ids in the rows of a CSV file, then copy the rows into a new CSV file. Code as follows:

```
import os
import csv

folder = os.listdir("[image folder]")
file_in = "[csv containing info rows]"
file_out = "[new csv to create]"

with open(file_in, 'r', newline='') as f_input, open(file_out, 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    writer = csv.writer(f_output)
    reader = csv.reader(f_input)
    writer.writerow(["ImageID", "LabelName", "XMin", "XMax", "YMin", "YMax", "IsGroupOf"]) #writes header of new csv
    for filename in folder:
        idx = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        for row in reader:
            if idx == row[0]:
                print(row)
                writer.writerow(row)
```

It outputs only the first matching id into the new CSV, instead of the actual number which is a few thousand. Sry for the simple task but I've been stumped for quite a while.

e.g.

Sample CSV:

```
ImageID,LabelName,XMin,XMax,YMin,YMax,IsGroupOf
0001eeaf4aed83f9,/m/0cmf2,0.022673031,0.9642005,0.07103825,0.80054647,0
00075905539074f2,/m/04yx4,0.020477816,0.32935154,0.0956023,0.665392,0
00075905539074f2,/m/04yx4,0.3208191,0.63993174,0,0.6596558,0
00075905539074f2,/m/04yx4,0.6757679,0.9914676,0.17208412,0.94837475,0
0007cebe1b2ba653,/m/07mhn,0.7359882,0.9262537,0.022123894,0.40265486,0
0007cebe1b2ba653,/m/0bt9lr,0.42035398,0.7935103,0.18141593,0.7212389,0
0007cebe1b2ba653,/m/01g317,0.7345133,0.9321534,0,0.36946902,0
0007d6cf88afaa4a,/m/0bt9lr,0.17342657,0.9020979,0.21678321,0.94172496,0
0008e425fb49a2bf,/m/0bt9lr,0.22610295,0.7150735,0.11170213,0.93439716,0
0009bad4d8539bb4,/m/0cmf2,0.2945508,0.70544916,0.34070796,0.5154867,0
```

3 sample images in folder: 0001eeaf4aed83f9.jpg, 0007cebe1b2ba653.jpg, 0009bad4d8539bb4.jpg

Expected output CSV:

```
ImageID,LabelName,XMin,XMax,YMin,YMax,IsGroupOf
0001eeaf4aed83f9,/m/0cmf2,0.022673031,0.9642005,0.07103825,0.80054647,0
0007cebe1b2ba653,/m/07mhn,0.7359882,0.9262537,0.022123894,0.40265486,0
0007cebe1b2ba653,/m/0bt9lr,0.42035398,0.7935103,0.18141593,0.7212389,0
0007cebe1b2ba653,/m/01g317,0.7345133,0.9321534,0,0.36946902,0
0009bad4d8539bb4,/m/0cmf2,0.2945508,0.70544916,0.34070796,0.5154867,0
```

Comment: Is the values of `idx` and `row[0]` are same and is case sensitve. Try `idx.lower() == row[0].lower()`

Comment: All the IDs are already in lowercase for idx and row[0]

Comment: Have you beren using the debugger? Step by step you should be able to see the contents of id / idx variables

Comment: @zy_125 post few rows from few files and expected output.

Comment: it seems that idx is not being iterated over all filenames and rows

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following approach. Firstly, use `glob.glob()` to only get the `jpg` files. A set can be used to hold all of the filenames that are found (without their extensions).

Now you can just read the sample CSV file in a row at a time and use a simple `in` check to test if the `ImageID` is one of the file names in the set.

For example:

```
import glob
import csv
import os

files = {os.path.splitext(filename)[0] for filename in glob.glob("*.jpg")}
file_in = "sample.csv"
file_out = "output.csv"

with open(file_in, 'r', newline='') as f_input, open(file_out, 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)

    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(header)

    for row in csv_input:
        if row[0] in files:    # Is ImageID one of the filenames found?
            print(row)
            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

This would give you an `output.csv` file as follows:

```
ImageID,LabelName,XMin,XMax,YMin,YMax,IsGroupOf
0001eeaf4aed83f9,/m/0cmf2,0.022673031,0.9642005,0.07103825,0.80054647,0
0007cebe1b2ba653,/m/07mhn,0.7359882,0.9262537,0.022123894,0.40265486,0
0007cebe1b2ba653,/m/0bt9lr,0.42035398,0.7935103,0.18141593,0.7212389,0
0007cebe1b2ba653,/m/01g317,0.7345133,0.9321534,0,0.36946902,0
0009bad4d8539bb4,/m/0cmf2,0.2945508,0.70544916,0.34070796,0.5154867,0
```